# Find the different letter

Tags: code-golf, image-processing, optical-char-recognition

You may have seen puzzles like this:

> Find the `0`:
>   `OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO0OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO`

The challenge is to write a program that finds the index of the different letter given an image.

#### Input

Input will be an `Image`. The image will consist of *one line* of *black* text in the *Helvetica 24 pt.* font on a *white* background. The text will consist from a selection of two characters: one character that is repeated, and one character that appears only once. For instance:

[image: Sample Input]

#### Output

Output will be an `Integer`, the index of the different character. In the example above, the output will be `4`. (Note that indices of a string start at `0`)

#### Program Specifications

As per usual for code golf, the shortest program wins.

---

### Test Cases

[image] `=> 10`
[image] `=> 11`
[image] `=> 5`
[image] `=> 16`
[image] `=> 10`
[image] `=> 21`
[image] `=> 20`
[image] `=> 13`
[image] `=> 11`
[image] `=> 4`
[image] `=> 7`

Comment: Pedantic note: your real-world example isn't a puzzle per se. It's more of an amusing eye-game.

Comment: How is this scored?

Comment: It's a code golf, so the shortest program that successfully outputs the answer to each of the examples.

Comment: Will the difference ever be at the beginning?

Comment: Yes, it can be there, although none are included in the examples.

Comment: Note that the shortest answer for some languages may actually be hard-coding the results and choosing one based on something like the size of the input image (which I assume is not allowed).

Comment: @AMACB "although none are included in the examples", then it might be a good idea to change that ;). Also what's the minimum number of characters we have to handle? (At least 3 I  guess, or can we assume it's more than that?) There should also be a test case for that minimum.

Comment: (Pity that the input is an image and not a string...)

Comment: will there always be at least one completely white column of pixels between characters?

Answer (score 6):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>31</s> 32 bytes

```
{1⍳⍨+⌿∘.≡⍨{⍵/⍨~∧⌿⍵}¨⍵⊂⍨2>/∧⌿1,⍵}
```

`⎕IO←0` to get indices starting with 0 (per OP), and which is anyway default in many APL systems.

`1,⍵` prepend a column of white pixels (to ensure margin)
`∧⌿` boolean for each column if all-white (vertical AND-reduction)
`2>/` boolean at each character's left edge (pair-wise greater-than)
`⍵⊂⍨` split into blocks beginning at each TRUE.
`{`…`}¨` for each block
`∧⌿⍵` boolean for each column if all-white (vertical AND-reduction)
`⍵/⍨~` columns that are not [all-white]
`∘.≡⍨` match each element to all elements
`+⌿` number of blocks identical to each block (vertical plus-reduction)
`1⍳⍨` index of first one (i.e. unique element)

Assumes the image is black (0) and white (1) pixels in the matrix `I`, and that there is at least one all-white pixel column between characters.

```
      f←{1⍳⍨+⌿∘.≡⍨{⍵/⍨~∧⌿⍵}¨⍵⊂⍨2>/∧⌿1,⍵}
```

"!I!!":

```
      ⊢I←6 12⍴(13/1),(22⍴0 1 1),(5/1),0,(8/1),(10⍴0 1 1),13/1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
      f I
1
```

"mmnmm":

```
      ⊢I←7 31⍴(94/1),0 0,(∊0 1⌽¨2/⊂12⍴6↑1 0 1 1),0 1,(62⍴1 1 1,(⊢,⌽)(14⍴0 1)),33/1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1     
      f I
2
```

Comment: Can't you completely remove the `{⍵/⍨~∧⌿⍵}¨` and remain with only `{1⍳⍨+⌿∘.≡⍨⍵⊂⍨2>/∧⌿1,⍵}`?

Comment: @lstefano Then it would stop working if there was varying amounts of white-space.

Comment: I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 125 bytes

```
StringCases[#,x:Except[StringCases[#~StringTake~3,x_~~___~~x_:>x][[1]]]:>Position[Characters@#,x]][[1,1,1]]-1&@*TextRecognize
```

Ahh, Mathemeatica builtins. So amazing. (And so long...)
Blows up on |/! :/; ,/. `/' and blows up differently on m/n.

Comment: How many inputs does this work for? My copy won't recognise any text in the first example (pipes and exclamation mark) for example.

Unless I'm missing something I have identical performance with 
`Length[Split[Characters@TextRecognize@#][[1]]] &`

Comment: Oops, forgot about Split....And it relies on Mathematica's built in text recognizer...And you can never trust it.

Comment: I'll post mine as a separate solution then.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 46 bytes

```
Length@First@Split@Characters@TextRecognize@#&
```

Same failures as the other mathematica solution as it relies on the same `TextRecognize` function.

Comment: Bytesave: `Length@First@Split@Characters@TextRecognize@#&`

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Cheers

Comment: Too bad it's just long enough that `@*` doesn't save.